# Enviar email desde varias direcciones laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, email

Tengo 2 email para enviar notificaciones a mis usuarios uno es info@midominio.com y el otro no-responder@midominio.com el asunto es que en el archivo .env solo puedo configurar uno si agrego otra configuración no lo toma de que forma puedo configurar ambos correos para el envió de las notificaciones

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar el metodo `from()`

```
/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('example@example.com')
                ->view('emails.orders.shipped');
}
```

Deberás usarlo en tu clase mailable.
Más información en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#configuring-the-sender)